# OpenXava Entity security

Tags: java, security, openxava

How could I show entities based on logged in user role? So if user logged in with admin role he will get access to all system elements and if he logged in as user he will get a subset of the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With OpenXava you can choose to produce a portlets based application or a normal webapp war, then you have two options here: 1).- Deploy you portlets' war into some portlet container like Liferay and then take advance of Liferay security schemas and other features of Liferay.

On the other hand, if you choose a webapp war you could take a look to this (not free) add-on http://www.openxava.org/naviox ... or then you could implement your security layer taking advance of some tool like Spring Security, here is a minuteproject blog entry with an extended example http://minuteproject.blogspot.com/2012/02/adding-spring-security-to-openxava.html .... I have not tested this last example, in fact I had some problems when I tried to integrate Spring in other OpenXava project for ActiveMQ JMS (and then I did follow other way) ... but maybe it could work if you follow the same steps and do that for Spring  Security into your OpenXava application.